# DDD: need two events to be raised for single handler

Tags: events, event-handling, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

How can I make sure I have received event (A) from an aggregate and event (B) from another aggregate before invoking a method from a third aggregate in the event handler? For example, I need productPaid event and productInStock event to buy a product?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can do a query in the handler to some aggregate to check if the other event already happened.
Or, you need a "process manager" instead of an "event handler".
You need a state that is shared by the two event handlers, something that when you receive an event allows you to record that it happened (some storage), and when you handle an event you can check if you already received the other one.

You can think to a process manager like an aggregate that receives events instead of commands (it cannot reject them!)